# Either cloning entire metadata from one file to another or simply removing single metadata lines

Tags: terminal, metadata, exif, exiftool

I am trying to make a file metadata (PDF) identical to another file (PDF). I am on a MacBook Pro and I have installed the exiftool.
While the exfitool is mostly able to do the job, there are few lines that I don't want in the destination file (that don't exist in the source file).

To be more specific:

```
Creator Tool: ...
XMP Toolkit: ...
Metadata date: ...
```

I can leave the `Creator Tool` but I must delete the `XMP Toolkit` line and need to either modify or delete `the Metadata date`.
What could I do? Do you have maybe another tool to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cpdf -print-metadata in.pdf > metadata.xml` to extract the XMP metadata to a file. Then you can delete the bits you don't like, and use `cpdf -set-metadata metadata.xml in.pdf -o out.pdf` to inject the new metadata back in. You can find the free version of cpdf here:

https://community.coherentpdf.com

If your file also has old-style (non-XMP) metadata, you can use some of the other functions in Chapter 11 of the manual:

https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf

Comment: I am using the prebuilt command line tool and the metadata.xml file is empty.

Comment: Then your file has no XMP metadata, so I'm not sure what exiftool is showing. Can you supply an example file?

Comment: PDFs can also have [PDF metadata](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html).  It's an older standard.

Comment: Right, but not with "Metadata" date or "XMP toolkit" entries, as OP shows above. Run `cpdf -info in.pdf` to see any and all information.

Answer (score 0):

Using exiftool, you command would be

`exiftool -TagsFromFile Source.pdf -All:All --CreatorTool --MetadataDate -XMPToolkit= target.pdf`

This will copy all the tags in Source.pdf to the exact same locations, exluding `Creator` and `MetadataDate`.  It also deletes the `XMPToolkit` which exiftool would write by default.

It will not copy any custom tags.  For example, in Adobe Reader, any metadata created under Document Properties->Custom tab will not be copied by exiftool, as exiftool needs a definition so it knows how to write a tag.

Finally, all edits exiftool makes are **reversible**. See 3rd paragraph on the [PDF Tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html). This is because exiftool uses incremental updates in PDFs.  See [Foxit's Incremental Updates in PDF files page](https://www.debenu.com/kb/incremental-updates/).  To make the changes permanent, the file must be re-linearized.  This can be done using [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) and probably some other PDF tools

`qpdf --linearize in.pdf out.pdf`

Comment: This command can also be done in batch, but it would require knowing the location of the source and target filenames.